# Is it possible to install a package from a repository on Gitlab using Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, gitlab

I am trying to get composer to download a library from my repository on Gitlab, however, it does not have a composer.json file in it so I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
    "require": {
        "username/repository-name"
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "version": "dev-master",
            "name": "username/repository-name",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://gitlab.com/username/repository.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }],
```

Comment: have you tried? you also need to specify the version in require

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer and it works for me here (the last answer, not the accepted answer):

[Using Composer and Private Repository on GIthub using VCS on Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400378/using-composer-and-private-repository-on-github-using-vcs-on-build-server)

This is what I make it works:

```
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
          "name": "username/repository",
          "version": "0.1.0",
          "type": "package",
          "source": {
              "url": "git@gitlab.com:username/repository.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "master"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "require": {           
        "username/repository": "*"
    },
```

Comment: Hello I followed this procedure. But I encountered a problem, it seems that the autoload for the package does not work. Have you experienced this? Any workarounds?

Comment: I've the same. I suggests to add the autoload section to composer.json. Better approach for me is to add a composer.json to the package too, with its own autoload section.

Comment: So well written - just copy-paste and rename, thank you!

Comment: @schellingerht This question was specifically about repositories without a composer.json - if you add a composer.json to the repository you can use a regular VCS package as shown in the docs here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Comment: Why do you require "*" and not a specific version? (on a build server this might be ok, on production it is not good practice - problem is people will copy-paste snippets ...)