# Composer failed to clone git repo

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm trying to get a development version of a module in my private GitLab repository.

Using what I've found in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781422/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-from-a-repository-on-gitlab-using-composer), my project's composer.json is:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://git.amh.net.au"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "amh-framework/amh-framework",
                "version": "dev-develop",
                "type": "package",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git.amh.net.au:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/amh-framework/amh-framework.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "amh-framework/amh-framework": "dev-develop",
    }
}
```

But when I run `composer update`, it throws a RuntimeException:

```
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout '' '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && cd '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && git remote add composer '' && git fetch composer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

fatal: repository '' does not exist
```

The output from `composer update -vvv` is:

```
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
  - Installing amh-framework/amh-framework (dev-develop 4d135f4)
Executing command (CWD): git --version
    Cloning 4d135f4b01dc896ffc722d8e24cc106d38cb4602
Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout '' '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && cd '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && git remote add composer '' && git fetch composer
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Failed: [RuntimeException] Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout '' '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && cd '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/vendor/amh-framework/amh-framework' && git remote add composer '' && git fetch composer

fatal: repository '' does not exist
```

So, it does seem to check the repo to get the latest commit (4d135f4b01dc896ffc722d8e24cc106d38cb4602) - but it's failing when cloning.

I can manually clone the project, so it doesn't appear to be permissions:

```
git clone git.amh.net.au:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/amh-framework/amh-framework.git
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is it that your complete composer.json file or are you missing something in it ? Because validating it as a json file gives me two errors.

Comment: does it work better now I've fully enclosed the object?

Comment: Yes it does after removing the trailing comma at the end of line 17. So, why is it not working for you ?

Comment: If I knew that, I wouldn't be asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to ordering of repositories - we're using satis to as a private package server. For some reason, satis says that the dev-master branch is available, but wouldn't correctly provide it (it works for tags, though).

By changing the file so that the git repo is listed ahead of satis, it works:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.amh.net.au:amh-framework/amh-test.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://svn.amh.net.au:8002"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "amh-framework/amh-test": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories), all you need is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "amh-framework/amh-framework": "dev-develop"
    },
    "repositories": [ 
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.amh.net.au:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/amh-framework/amh-framework.git"
        }
     ]
}
```

Make sure to use an actual branch for version.

Comment: I still get the error - and this was what I originally attempted. I arrived at the my current attempt after reading other people's questions here.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone ''
fatal: repository '' does not exist
```

Seems like in example above Composer is trying to clone a non existent repository.

git clone --no-checkout ---> '' <--- '/var/checkouts/reports/reporter/v...

So maybe somewhere in your composer.json file your url is empty.

Also, I found atleast two problems in the composer.json file above.

> Error: Parse error on line 1: "repositories": [{  "type": "packa
> --------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
>
> Error: Parse error on line 17: ...k": "dev-develop",  }}
> ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', got '}'

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was missing the `auth.json` credentials for git to be able to fetch the repositories due to the fact that they were private ones.

like:

```
{
  "github-oauth": {
    "github.com": "personal-access-key"
  }
}
```