# Load composer package from private gitlab

Tags: json, git, composer-php, typo3

In my composer setup I load packages from 2 repos. One composer repo and a private gitlab repo. When I try to do a composer install on my local windows machine, I get the following error messages:

> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found. fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the
>   correct access rights and the repository exists. ... The requested
>   package sv-test/testextension could not be found in any version, there
>   may be a typo in the package name.

Authentification is done via lokal ssh-key and password, that doesn`t seem to be the problem. What`s wrong with my setup?

The composer.json of the project looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@gitlab.xydevbox.de:sv-test/Testproject.git"
        }
    ],
    "name": "svdev/master-dev-box",
    "description": "",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://www.xydevbox.de/",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sacha Vorbeck",
            "email": "sacha.vorbeck@xydevbox.de",
            "homepage": "https://www.xydevbox.de/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "sv-testbox/testextension": "*",
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.5",
        "typo3/cms": "^8.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "process-timeout": 2000,
        "preferred-install": {
            "typo3/cms": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
            "web-dir": "web"
        }
    }
}
```

The composer.json from the package to be included from the gitlab private repo looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "sv-testbox/testextension",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "https://www.xydevbox.de/",
  "license": ["GPL-2.0+"],
  "keywords": ["TYPO3 CMS"],
  "version": "master",
  "dist": {
    "url": "git@gitlab.xydevbox.de:sv-test/Testproject.git",
    "type": "git"
  }
}
```

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781422/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-from-a-repository-on-gitlab-using-composer won't help, perhaps require a version "*@dev" in order to allow for "whatever version, not only stable"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the latest composer version 1.5.2 is something for you if you take a look at the release notes

> - Fixed GitLabDriver looping endlessly in some conditions
> - Fixed
>     GitLabDriver support for unauthenticated requests
> - Fixed GitLab zip
>     downloads not triggering credentials prompt if unauthenticated
> - Fixed
>     path repository support of COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION, it now applies to
>     all path repos within the same git repository
> - Fixed path repository
>     handling of copies to avoid copying VCS files and others
> - Fixed
>     sub-directory call to ignore list and create-project commands as well
>     as calls to Composer using --working-dir
> - Fixed invalid warning
>     appearing when calling remove on an non-stable package

https://github.com/composer/composer/releases

Comment: thanks, I already have the latest version running. Meanwhile, I found out that there is a type "gitlab" that I can use instead of "git". 
I also found some helpful info here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784809/how-to-use-a-specific-tag-version-with-composer-and-a-private-git-repository

Now the extension from git is copied to the vendor dir but not into web/typo3conf/ext/ . Do I have to configure something for this to happen?

Comment: normally the type "typo3-cms-extension" is the one which is responsible that a package is copied into typo3conf/ext/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Georg and NextThursday. With some help on TYPO3 slack I finally got it running. The replace part was missing. I also learned that one should not edit composer.json files manually - always use the command line options to modify it. This example: https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/blob/master/composer.json was also helpful.

project composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/svorbeck/masterconfig"
        }
    ],
    "name": "svorbeck/demo",
    "description": "",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://xydevbox.de/",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sacha Vorbeck",
            "email": "sacha.vorbeck@xydevbox.de",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "svorbeck/masterconfig": "dev-master",
        "typo3/cms": "^8.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "process-timeout": 2000,
        "preferred-install": {
            "typo3/cms": "source",
            "svorbeck/masterconfig": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
            "web-dir": "web"
        },
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
            "install-extension-dummy": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

ext composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "svorbeck/masterconfig",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "svorbeck master configuration",
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^8.7"
    },
    "replace": {
        "masterconfig": "self.version",
        "svorbeck/masterconfig": "self.version"
    }
}
```