# PHP - how to make git trace local changes done in private packages downloaded via compsoer

Tags: php, git, composer-php, gitignore

In my company we're working on a PHP application which uses composer to manage dependencies.
Some of these dependencies are our own private packages, which have their own different git repositories (the vendor directory, where they stay, is in gitignore).

My question is, how can we get git to trace changes on these packages, so we can easily commit them (currently we just manually copy the changed files to a locally cloned version of the package, and commit from there).

Comment: Maybe this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400378/using-composer-and-private-repository-on-github-using-vcs-on-build-server

Comment: We actually don't have problem with composer - all packages downloaded ok. Our problem is the work flow: how to make git trace changes in those repositories and commit them easily?