# Composer to download private GitHub repositories

Tags: php, git, github, ssh, composer-php

I cannot download github private repos with composer

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get the following error

> The "https://api.github.com/repos/company/private1" file could not be
>   downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

but i can easily download these private repos using `git clone`

Composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:company/private1.git",
        "options": {
            "ssh2": {
                "username": "githubusername",
                "pubkey_file": "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                "privkey_file": "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:company/private2.git",
        "options": {
            "ssh2": {
                "username": "githubusername",
                "pubkey_file": "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                "privkey_file": "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa"
            }
        }
    }
],

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.1.3",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module": "dev-master",
    "company/private": "dev-master",
    "company/private2": "dev-master"
}
```

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400378/using-composer-and-private-repository-on-github-using-vcs-on-build-server) but it doesnot work

SSH2 PECL is also enabled.

I have also created config file `vim ~/home/.ssh/config`

with the following details

```
host www.github.com
User githubusername
HostName github.com
IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but still i cannot download the private repos using composer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your composer.json file, you do not need the options in your repository section, just the `type` and `url`.

### SSH

Over on GitHub, under `Profile...Settings`, there is a `SSH and GPG Keys` tab.  This is where you load up the public side of your SSH key to access GitHub from your  machine (where the private key is stored).

See their documentation [Generating an SSH Key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) which steps you through this process.  It also steps you through the SSH Agent storage for the private side of the key.

### Personal Access Tokens

When you invoke `composer install` if you have not set up an access token, but need one, Composer will prompt you to generate it and a URL to use to accomplish this. You can use that URL and it will generate a once-seen API token that you then load up on composer to access GitHub.  From the GitHub website:

> Personal access tokens function like ordinary OAuth access tokens.
>   They can be used instead of a password for Git over HTTPS.

If you don't see this automatic prompt, then here is how to do it manually:

- Go to `GitHub...Settings...Personal` access tokens
- Press the `Generate new token` button
- Enter something meaningful to you in the `Token Description`
- Check the `repo` checkbox (it will automatically check the three checkboxes underneath)
- Press the `Generate token` button at the bottom of the page
- Copy the token

Back on your server, tell composer about the token:

- `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <token>`
- `composer install`

Comment: yea for some reason  `php composer.phar update` doesnot work but `php composer.phar install` works... Idk why

Comment: Weird, I haven't seen that problem.  You might want to delete the lock file (or rename it so you have a backup).  Then you can do a update to generate a fresh lock file and see if install then works properly, maybe composer is a bit confused :)

Comment: what's the difference betwwen personal toke / ci cd token and github token ?