# php git pull not working in private repository?

Tags: git

I want to automate the task of 'git pull' from Linux server.
It worked in public repository.(testing...)

But it doesn't not working in private repository!
Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: What is the relevance of PHP here ? Can you put more description with examples of what you have tried already. ?

Comment: PHP Code: `shell_exec('git pull')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell composer about your PAT (Personal Access Token), which would allow you to access the private repos that you own (not private repos owned by other users though).
Make sure you have [created a PAT first](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <token>
```

See "[composer to download private github repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702735/6309)"